# React Events Lifecycle

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know how to get the onClick event to fire before the onBlur?

Using the emulator in Chrome dev tools that is the behavior I see for mobile.  But on desktop the onClick never fires.

```
class EventLifeCycleTest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        event: '',
      divStyle: {display: 'none'}
    };
  }

  handleOnBlur() {
    this.setState({
        event: this.state.event + ' onBlur',
      divStyle: {display: 'none'}
    });
  }

  handleOnFocus() {
    this.setState({
        event: this.state.event + ' onFocus',
      divStyle: {display: 'block'}
    });
  }

  handleOnClick() {
    this.setState({event: this.state.event + ' onClick',});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
          <input 
            onFocus={() => this.handleOnFocus()} 
            onBlur={() => this.handleOnBlur()} 
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          Event: {this.state.event}
        </div>
        <div style={this.state.divStyle}>
          <button onClick={() => this.handleOnClick()} >Click Me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmeskill/m9r87jnt/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `onMouseDown` instead of `onClick` in your case.

usually the order goes

```
mousedown
blur
mouseup
click
```